# Android: I created a bitmap from canvas and save it to "sdcard/folder/subfolder" but I couldn't decode it to a image view

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I've created a bitmap from canvas. Save it to my "/sdcard/folder/subfolder/file.png"

I want to get this png file into imageview after saving it. I tried this by using BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/folder/subfolder/file.png"); method. But it returned nothing. There is no image on imageview.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Show your code how you save bitmap from canvas into PNG and how you later use saved image

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/subfolder/file.png";//or "folder/subfolder.."
```